# create dependency between concurrent tasks in Python asyncio

Tags: python, concurrency, task, python-asyncio

I have two tasks in a consumer/producer relationship, separated by a `asyncio.Queue`. If the producer task fails, I'd like the consumer task to also fail as soon as possible, and not wait indefinitely on the queue. The consumer task can be created(spawned) independently from the producer task.

In general terms, I'd like to implement a dependency between two tasks, such that the failure of one is also the failure of the other, while keeping those two tasks concurrent(i.e. one will not await the other directly).

What kind of solutions(e.g. patterns) could be used here?

Basically, I'm thinking of [erlang's "links"](http://erlangbyexample.org/links).

I think it may be possible to implement something similar using callbacks, i.e. `asyncio.Task.add_done_callback`

Thanks!

Comment: what's the scope of the dependency? Are you interested at the task level? if a failure occurs in the producer should it be propagated to the consumer? the process level? if a failure occurs in the producer should all both stop? Is there a specific behavior you're trying to avoid?

Comment: I think I already answered some of those questions. Yes, a failure in the producer task should propagate to the consumer. The behavior I'm trying to avoid is the consumer being oblivious to the producer's death and waiting indefinitely on the queue. I want the consumer to be notified of the producer's death, and have a chance to react. or just fail, and that even while it's also waiting on the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment:

> The behavior I'm trying to avoid is the consumer being oblivious to the producer's death and waiting indefinitely on the queue. I want the consumer to be notified of the producer's death, and have a chance to react. or just fail, and that even while it's also waiting on the queue.

Other than the [answer presented by Yigal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776605/4298200), another way is to set up a third task that monitors the two and *cancels* one when the other one finishes. This can be generalized to any two tasks:

```
async def cancel_when_done(source, target):
    assert isinstance(source, asyncio.Task)
    assert isinstance(target, asyncio.Task)
    try:
        await source
    except:
        # SOURCE is a task which we expect to be awaited by someone else
        pass
    target.cancel()
```

Now when setting up the producer and the consumer, you can link them with the above function. For example:

```
async def producer(q):
    for i in itertools.count():
        await q.put(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(.2)
        if i == 7:
            1/0

async def consumer(q):
    while True:
        val = await q.get()
        print('got', val)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    p = loop.create_task(producer(queue))
    c = loop.create_task(consumer(queue))
    loop.create_task(cancel_when_done(p, c))
    await asyncio.gather(p, c)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to propagate the exception through the queue, combined with delegation of the work handling:

```
class ValidWorkLoad:
    async def do_work(self, handler):
        await handler(self)


class HellBrokeLoose:
    def __init__(self, exception):
        self._exception = exception

    async def do_work(self, handler):
        raise self._exception


async def worker(name, queue):
    async def handler(work_load):
        print(f'{name} handled')

    while True:
        next_work = await queue.get()
        try:
            await next_work.do_work(handler)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'{name} caught exception: {type(e)}: {e}')
            break
        finally:
            queue.task_done()


async def producer(name, queue):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # Produce some work, or fail while trying
            new_work = ValidWorkLoad()
            i += 1
            if i % 3 == 0:
                raise ValueError(i)
            await queue.put(new_work)
            print(f'{name} produced')
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  # Preempt just for the sake of the example
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception occurred')
            await queue.put(HellBrokeLoose(e))
            break


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
producer_coro = producer('Producer', queue)
consumer_coro = worker('Consumer', queue)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(producer_coro, consumer_coro))
loop.close()
```

Which outputs:

> Producer produced
>
> Consumer handled
>
> Producer produced
>
> Consumer handled
>
> Exception occurred
>
> Consumer caught exception: <class 'ValueError'>: 3

Alternatively you could skip the delegation, and designate an item that signals the worker to stop. When catching an exception in the producer you put that designated item in the queue.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way. I'm not sure I like it because it conflates the logic of the producer-consumer relationship to the logic of the dependency/error handling strategy. Also, if I want to generalize to two arbitrary tasks(that do not necessarily fit the producer-consumer model), I'd like to not depend on a queue existing between the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
import asyncio
def link_tasks(t1: Union[asyncio.Task, asyncio.Future], t2: Union[asyncio.Task, asyncio.Future]):
    """
    Link the fate of two asyncio tasks,
    such that the failure or cancellation of one
    triggers the cancellation of the other
    """
    def done_callback(other: asyncio.Task, t: asyncio.Task):
        # TODO: log cancellation due to link propagation
        if t.cancelled():
            other.cancel()
        elif t.exception():
            other.cancel()
    t1.add_done_callback(functools.partial(done_callback, t2))
    t2.add_done_callback(functools.partial(done_callback, t1))
```

This uses `asyncio.Task.add_done_callback` to register callbacks that will cancel the other task if either one fails or is cancelled.